# Jmeter and Graphing Sampler Errors over Time

Tags: load, jmeter, performance-testing

Is there any way to graph sampler errors over time after running a test plan in JMeter?

I had a test plan execute for an hour, and was watching the command line summary results go by. After about 45 minutes errors started appearing in the results. I looked for a listener which allowed me graph the error percent over time but wasn't able to find anything.

Looking at the results file it appears the sampler results saves a timestamp... Would it be possible to write my own tool that reads the results file (xml) and use the timestamp on each result to build this graph?

I am assuming ts in the example below is a timestamp?

```
<httpSample t="1" lt="0" ts="1446662820905" s="false" lb="[POST] Account Accept Invite Pass" rc="Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException" rm="Non HTTP response message: The target server failed to respond" tn="Load Tests Accept Invite Workflow 3-2" dt="text" by="1919">
```

Comment: Any feedback on answers, if OK it should be accepted and upvoted

Answer (score 1):

No need to write a tool for this. [Import the XML in MS Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-XML-data-6eca3906-d6c9-4f0d-b911-c736da817fa4) and create a graph/chart on your own.

Comment: I tried this and apparently my result file is too big for excel to import. I think I'm going to look into ways to filter the xml down further and try excel again.

Answer (score 1):

To compute this you have at least 2 options:

- 1/ http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/
- 2/ Or you can use this custom version of JMeter that contains a new Reporting feature:

  https://github.com/ubikloadpack/jmeter/releases/tag/2.14-preview-ubikloapack-beta

You can see what it shows here:

```
http://ubikloadpack.com/donations/dashboard/
```

This feature is being donated to JMeter, if you feel it's useful, then :

- Register at http://jmeter.apache.org/mail2.html
- The send a mail saying you like it here to JMeter Users List user at jmeter.apache.org with subject "Re: Donation of a New Dashboard for JMeter : Questions and more"

Comment: I don't see any graphs for error% over time in either of the links above. Is the option there and I am not seeing it?

Comment: What about http://ubikloadpack.com/donations/dashboard/content/pages/Throughput.html#codesPerSecond

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK Following links are broken on doc -

http://ubikloadpack.com/donations/dashboard/docs/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html
http://ubikloadpack.com/donations/dashboard/docs/usermanual/get-started.html#options

I would especially be interested in command line option. Thanks for dashboard, looks very promising.

Comment: all code is now in Jmeter upcoming 3.0, download nigthly build and read user manual